# How to echo only existing folders with GLOB_ONLYDIR (php)

Tags: php

Example:

```
$dirs = glob('./*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
echo "<a href='$dirs[0]'>  <img src='$dirs[0]/thumb.jpg'/></a> ";
echo "<a href='$dirs[1]'>  <img src='$dirs[1]/thumb.jpg'/></a> ";
```

My problem is some folders have only one, some have for example 2 subfolders
how can I echo only existing folders?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

So what I want is to create a php file what generates a gallery from all folders in a folder where the file placed.
but if I using echo like above for example:

```
$dirs = glob('./*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
echo "<a href='$dirs[0]'>  <img src='$dirs[0]/thumb.jpg'/></a> ";
echo "<a href='$dirs[1]'>  <img src='$dirs[1]/thumb.jpg'/></a> ";
echo "<a href='$dirs[2]'>  <img src='$dirs[2]/thumb.jpg'/></a> ";
echo "<a href='$dirs[3]'>  <img src='$dirs[3]/thumb.jpg'/></a> ";
echo "<a href='$dirs[4]'>  <img src='$dirs[4]/thumb.jpg'/></a> ";
echo "<a href='$dirs[5]'>  <img src='$dirs[5]/thumb.jpg'/></a> ";
```

and the folder have only 3 folders inside than I got 3 empty thumb. because 
$dirs[3] and above doesn't exist. :(

Comment: I have to recommend this approach over glob.. http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php check the first user comment for guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a recursive function in order to get more than level 1 directories. You can try something like:

```
function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0)
{
    $files = glob($pattern, $flags);

    foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir)
    {
        $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
    }

    return $files;
}

print_r(glob_recursive('/var/www/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR));
```

This example will only print the directories under your `/var/www` folder. Be really careful with performance, if your directory structure is too big it can be slow.

The [original source](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php#106595) of the method.

**EDIT:**

I think what you want is to itinerate the array woth a foreach loop so you don't get empty thumbnails:

```
$dirs = glob('./*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach ($dirs as $index=>$dir){
  echo "<a href='$dirs[$index]'>  <img src='$dirs[$index]/thumb.jpg'/></a> ";
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi!Thanks for the answer, but maybe my question not pointed out my problem.Edited. :) @asurbernardo

Comment: @tibi888 I've edited the post. Check it out and tell me if it is what you are looking fo because I'm not sure I completly understand your problem.

Comment: @tibi888 Perfect mate, glad that was useful ;)

Comment: !Now (with your code) i have the same number of thumbs like folders so I getting somewhere! :) the problem now is it not outputs the dirs only:<a href='.'>  <img src='./thumb.jpg'/> @asurbernardo

Comment: @tibi888 Oooops my fault just rename the $key variable for $index I just got confused! (Updated)